# How can I connect the AspNetUsers table from Identity with another table?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

AspNetUsers table has an Id column that I want to use.

This is the "another table model" where I would like to create the fk for AspNetUsers table:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Profile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }    
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
        public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AspNetUsersId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I include the Identity tables in my application database, not a separate database. As long as the Identity tables are in your database, you can create relationships.

Comment: How can I create relationships?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)